# Network Selection disabled by WiFi Manager & Wi-Fi keeps disconnecting

Tags: wi-fi, networking, troubleshooting, developer-options

Android 7.1.2 drops WiFi connection. 
Wi-Fi verbose log says:

(network_selection_permamently_disabled)
network_selection_disabled_by_wifi_manager

[image: screenshot of network manager with extended info on wifi signals]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, the following WiFi Manager App was the reason:

> Wi-Fi Privacy Police (Prevent leaking sensitive data on WiFi)

The problem disappears whenever I disable this app. Here is how to disable it:

> (System) Settings / Memory / Apps started on boot / Wi-Fi Privacy Police / Start at boot: DISABLED

So you disabled the App's bootup autostart. Now reboot Android. 
After you have Android rebooted, check again Android's Wi-Fi settings: The error message NETWORK SELECTION DISABLED BY WIFI MANAGER should have disappeared.

Wi-Fi Privacy Police was actually a useful app for long time, till I noticed the unfortunate repeated interrupted WiFi connection. Below you have a screenshot of that app's functionality:

[image]

Comment: I add a similar problem on LineageOS 16.0 (Android 9). I had to go to Settings / Memory / Apps started on boot / Work profile setup / Start at boot: DISABLED